# vim exe default mapping

Tags: vim

I would like to execute from a function `<C-x><C-u>` (Complete func) even though if the user remapped `<C-x>` to something else like (`inoremap <C-x> icontrol-x<esc>`) .

I found this solution which is not really neat:

```
 :inoremap <f22> <c-x>
 :exec "normal i\<f22>\<c-u>"
```

Another suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Use `:normal!`. With a bang vim uses default actions.